# File opens as text file in browser when opened with PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sveltekit, file-system-access-api

I built a PWA from svelte-kit app. I want to open a particular type of file with my PWA. I created my PWA and defined file-handler in manifest.json. The app works as desired if I launch it using the icon on the desktop. However, when I launch the app while opening the file, instead of opening it using my PWA, it opens as a plain txt file in browser. What am I missing here?
Here are the contents of my manifest and service worker:
[Maifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKSxi.png)
[Service Worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfyQ2.png)

I have the code to process the file in +page.svelte
[code in +page.svetle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgEKO.png)

My expected behaviour is to call handleFileOnLaunch when the app is launched using "open with" when opening a file.